# Room links in chatrooms 'eat' the rest of text

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

[image]

Is it intentionnal that the chatroom 'frame' eats any text around?

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30455443#30455443

Comment: It's really the onebox, not the link. If you reverse the order, it won't onebox.